# PrimeFaces spinner with fixed number of digits

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I can't display nicely `p:spinner` numbers with a fixed number of digits:

```
<p:spinner value="#{myBean.myValue}" stepFactor="0.1">
```

with `myValue` being a double.
On the third up-click the number displayed is 0.30000000000000004 instead of 0.3. I know that this is normal floating-point behaviour, but I can't find a way to display the number nicely.

I have tried with using a `BigDecimal` initialized at "0.0" instead of a double. Same behaviour.

Finally I have tried with a default converter, supposing that the situation was too trivial for requiring a custom one:

```
<p:spinner value="#{myBean.myValue}" stepFactor="0.1" >
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="1" />
</p:spinner>
```

with the same effect.

Comment: The `p:spinner` increments/decrements purely client side (using JS), so any server side attempts to fix it won't have any effect. I suggest to report it as a bug to PF guys.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the hint. Reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5003).

Comment: I belive problem can be alleviated (not really solved) by maxDecimalNumber='1' in spinner

Comment: @skegg99, which PF version? I can't find maxDecimalNumber attribute for any component in 3.4 (this is the version I am using)

Comment: @perissf Not sure, have not been using primefaces for long time. But this thread suggests this workaround could be helpful http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23616&start=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug in PrimeFaces (specifically in its client-side Javasript). It was logged as [issue 4535](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4535) and fixed in version 3.5.2 and 4.0.